# Fill new column by appending suffixes to an existing field based on a condition on a third one (mapping)

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I'd like to know if there is a better solution than the following to construct a new column (`place_type_new`) by adding a suffix to the textual information of an existing column (`place_type`) based on the value of a third column (the number of `inhabitant` in the case shown here):

```sql
  UPDATE places_table SET place_type_new = CASE
      WHEN inhabitant = 0 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_XXXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_XXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_XS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 100 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_S'
      WHEN inhabitant = 2000 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_M'
      WHEN inhabitant = 5000 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_L'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10000 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_XL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20000 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_XXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 50000 AND place_type LIKE 'Village' THEN 'Village_XXXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 0 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_XXXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_XXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_XS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 100 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_S'
      WHEN inhabitant = 2000 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_M'
      WHEN inhabitant = 5000 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_L'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10000 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_XL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20000 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_XXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 50000 AND place_type LIKE 'VillagePart' THEN 'VillagePart_XXXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 0 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_XXXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_XXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_XS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 100 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_S'
      WHEN inhabitant = 2000 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_M'
      WHEN inhabitant = 5000 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_L'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10000 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_XL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20000 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_XXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 50000 AND place_type LIKE 'Neighborhood' THEN 'Neighborhood_XXXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 0 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_XXXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_XXS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_XS'
      WHEN inhabitant = 100 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_S'
      WHEN inhabitant = 2000 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_M'
      WHEN inhabitant = 5000 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_L'
      WHEN inhabitant = 10000 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_XL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 20000 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_XXL'
      WHEN inhabitant = 50000 AND place_type LIKE 'NeighborhoodPart' THEN 'NeighborhoodPart_XXXL'
      ELSE place_type
  END;
```

Here `Village`, `VillagePart`, `Neighborhood` and `NeighborhoodPart` are part of a larger set of places (for examples there are also `Town`, `City` and so on) and I only want this rule to apply for these 4 elements, hence my `LIKE` statements everywhere.

But I find this horribly ugly, but it's perfectly working. The suffix to append to the existing field values in the `places_table` in order to build the new `place_table_new` one, always matches the same number in the column `inhabitant` according to this pattern:

```
0     : XXXS
10    :  XXS
20    :   XS
100   :    S
2000  :    M
5000  :    L
10000 :   XL
20000 :  XXL
50000 : XXXL
```

Would it be better to build an intermediary table with this mapping in order to achieve this?

I'm using PostgreSQL 12 on Ubuntu 18.04. I also narrowed down the problem here to something as simple as I can, hopefully without forgetting something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reduce it to the following

> ```
> CREATE TABLE places_table(inhabitant INT,place_type VARCHAR(50),place_type_new VARCHAR(50) )
> ```

> ```
> iNSERT INTO places_table vaLUES (0,'Village',NULL)
> ,(50,'NeighborhoodPart',NULL),(10000,'Neighborhood',NULL),(10000,'city',NULL)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE places_table SET place_type_new = 
>  CASE wHEN place_type IN ('Village','VillagePart','Neighborhood','NeighborhoodPart') THEN
>    CASE
>       WHEN inhabitant = 0  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_XXXS')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 10  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_XXS')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 20  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_XS')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 100 THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_S')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 2000  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_M')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 5000  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_L')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 10000 THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_XL')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 20000  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_XXL')
>       WHEN inhabitant <= 50000  THEN CONCAT(place_type,'_XXXL')
>      ELSE place_type
>   END
> ELSE place_type
> END;
> ```

> ```
> seLECT * FROM places_table
> ```
>
> ```
> inhabitant | place_type       | place_type_new    
> ---------: | :--------------- | :-----------------
>          0 | Village          | Village_XXXS      
>         50 | NeighborhoodPart | NeighborhoodPart_S
>      10000 | Neighborhood     | Neighborhood_XL   
>      10000 | city             | city
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9a9c59af8d7c4b216addb2ec98f6c4c0)*

Comment: Thank you! You probably forgot to add something like `AND (place_type in ('Village','Neighborhood','NeighborhoodPart'))` after the numbers in all your `WHEN` statements. This is to reproduce the `LIKE` statements of my original queries, because, I didn't show it, but there are some other types of places for which I don't want to compute this new field, so keeping only the old value without any suffix is OK.

Comment: you didn't write that in your question

Comment: I fixed this by explaining it with more details ;-)

Comment: i changed the answer by adding the further case with all 4 places and i changed ithe inhabitants to <= which would make more sense, as the number shouldn't be that fix